# Can a prompt take two arguments at the same time?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if a prompt can take two arguments simultaneously, and store them in distinct variables.

**Example:**

```
var something = prompt(variable storing a number , variable storing a string)
console.log(variable storing a string);
```

Is it legal or just pure fantasy? Let me know if it needs more explanation.

Comment: this is very poor explanation please elaborate

Comment: No, it can't on it's own. `prompt()` returns a single string (what the user inputs). You'd have to parse it yourself.

Comment: Just [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) - Return a _string containing the text entered by the user, or null_ - So NO, it can't

Comment: What would that double prompt actually *look like*…? Have you ever seen such a thing in the wild?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's clear from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) that prompt can't do it

Answer (score 1):

the prompt function takes 2 arguments: the text to display and the default text of the input, so that would not work.

I'd suggest you either get the required data through 2 separate prompts or ask the user to provide both in a single prompt and then parse the returned string afterwards to separate the integer and the string.